# HackerRank: Climbing the Leaderboard

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a deal with a [HackerRank algorithm problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem).

It works at all cases, except 6-7-8-9. It gives timeout error. I had spent so much time at this level. Someone saw where is problem?

```
static long[] climbingLeaderboard(long[] scores, long[] alice)  
{
    //long[] ranks = new long[scores.Length];
    long[] aliceRanks = new long[alice.Length]; // same length with alice length
    long lastPoint = 0;
    long lastRank;
    for (long i = 0; i < alice.Length; i++)
    {
        lastPoint = scores[0];
        lastRank = 1;
        bool isIn = false; // if never drop in if statement 
        for (long j = 0; j < scores.Length; j++)
        {
            if (lastPoint != scores[j])  //if score is not same, raise the variable
            {
                lastPoint = scores[j];
                lastRank++;
            }

            if (alice[i] >= scores[j])
            {
                aliceRanks[i] = lastRank;
                isIn = true;
                break;
            }
            aliceRanks[i] = !isIn & j + 1 == scores.Length ? ++lastRank : aliceRanks[i]; //drop in here
        }
    }
    return aliceRanks;
}
```

Comment: While I encourage you to continue doing Hackerrank in your spare time to help hone your skills, it would help if you were a bit more specific about your actual issue. What _exactly_ are you having trouble with?

Comment: Also do report of how the debugger did or didn't help you.

Comment: "It works at all cases, except 6-7-8-9" is not enough to explain exactly what the problem is inline in the post. "I'm working on {link}" is not an acceptable way to ask question/provide details on SO - post must include enough information to stand on its own without any links.

Comment: You just need to find a more efficient way of determining where the next score belongs in the rankings.  What you currently have will run in n^2 time, but you can do better if you take advantage of the scores being in order.

Comment: You could do this in about 6 lines of linq, however im not sure you would understand it

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that utilizes [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch). This method returns the index of the searched number in the array, or if the number is not found then it returns a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element in the array. Binary search only works in sorted arrays.

```
public static int[] GetRanks(long[] scores, long[] person)
{
    var defaultComparer = Comparer<long>.Default;
    var reverseComparer = Comparer<long>.Create((x, y) => -defaultComparer.Compare(x, y));
    var distinctOrderedScores = scores.Distinct().OrderBy(i => i, reverseComparer).ToArray();
    return person
        .Select(i => Array.BinarySearch(distinctOrderedScores, i, reverseComparer))
        .Select(pos => (pos >= 0 ? pos : ~pos) + 1)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Usage example:

```
var scores = new long[] { 100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10 };
var alice = new long[] { 5, 25, 50, 120 };
var ranks = GetRanks(scores, alice);
Console.WriteLine($"Ranks: {String.Join(", ", ranks)}");
```

Output:

> Ranks: 6, 4, 2, 1

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved in **O(n)** time, no binary search needed at all. First, we need to extract the most useful piece of data given in the problem statement, which is,

> The existing leaderboard, ***scores***, is in descending order.
>
> Alice's scores, ***alice***, are in ascending order.

An approach that makes this useful is to create two pointers, one at the start of ***alice*** array, let's call it "***i***", and the second is at the end of ***scores*** array, let's call it "***j***". We then loop until ***i*** reaches the end of ***alice*** array and at each iteration, we check for three main conditions. We increment ***i*** by one if ***alice[i]*** is less than ***scores[j]*** because the next element of ***alice*** may be also less than the current element of ***scores***, or we decrement ***j*** if ***alice[i]*** is greater than ***scores[j]*** because we are sure that the next elements of ***alice*** are also greater than those elements discarded in ***scores***. The last condition is that if ***alice[i] == scores[j]***, we only increment ***i***.

I solved this question in C++, my goal here is to make you understand the algorithm, I think you can easily convert it to C# if you understand it. If there are any confusions, please tell me. Here is the code:

```
// Complete the climbingLeaderboard function below.
vector<int> climbingLeaderboard(vector<int> scores, vector<int> alice) {
    int j = 1, i = 1;
    // this is to remove duplicates from the scores vector
    for(i =1; i < scores.size(); i++){
        if(scores[i] != scores[i-1]){
            scores[j++] = scores[i];
        }
    }
    int size = scores.size();
    for(i = 0; i < size-j; i++){
        scores.pop_back();
    }
    vector<int> ranks;

    i = 0;
    j = scores.size()-1;
    while(i < alice.size()){
        if(j < 0){
            ranks.push_back(1);
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if(alice[i] < scores[j]){
            ranks.push_back(j+2);
            i++;
        } else if(alice[i] > scores[j]){
            j--;
        } else {
            ranks.push_back(j+1);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return ranks;
}
```

I think this may help you too:

> ***vector*** is like an array list that resizes itself.
>
> ***push_back()*** is inserting at the end of the vector.
>
> ***pop_back()*** is removing from the end of the vector.

Comment: Brilliant! I passed HR tests now, though reimplementing it on Perl. I've wasted my time initially barking up a wrong tree with Binary search. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

### Here is my solution with c#

```
public static List<int> climbingLeaderboard(List<int> ranked, List<int> player)
    {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            ranked = ranked.Distinct().ToList();
            var pLength = player.Count;
            var rLength = ranked.Count-1;
          
            int j = rLength;
            for (int i = 0; i < pLength; i++)
            {               
                for (; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if (player[i] == ranked[j])
                    {
                        result.Add(j + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(player[i] < ranked[j])
                    {
                        result.Add(j + 2);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(player[i] > ranked[j]&&j==0)
                    {
                        result.Add(1);
                        break;
                    }enter code here
                }
            }

            return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was bored so i gave this a go with *Linq* and heavily commented it for you,

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetRanks(long[] scores, long[] person)

   // Convert scores to a tuple
   => scores.Select(s => (scores: s, isPerson: false))

             // convert persons score to a tuple and concat
            .Concat(person.Select(s => (scores: s, isPerson: true)))

             // Group by scores
            .GroupBy(x => x.scores)

             // order by score
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)

             // select into an indexable tuple so we know everyones rank
            .Select((groups, i) => (rank: i, groups))

             // Filter the person
            .Where(x => x.groups.Any(y => y.isPerson))

             // select the rank
            .Select(x => x.rank);
```

**Usage**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var scores = new long[]{1, 34, 565, 43, 44, 56, 67};   
   var alice = new long[]{578, 40, 50, 67, 6};

   var ranks = GetRanks(scores, alice);

   foreach (var rank in ranks)
      Console.WriteLine(rank);

}
```

**Output**

```
1
3
6
8
10
```

Comment: The array `scores` is expected to be in descending order, and the array `alice` in ascending order. Without proper ordering, the expected output is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given constraint brute-force solution will not be efficient for the problem.
you have to optimize your code and the key part here is to look up for exact place which can be effectively done by using binary search.

**Here is the solution using binary search:-**

```
static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice) {
        int n = scores.length;
        int m = alice.length;

        int res[] = new int[m];
        int[] rank = new int[n];

        rank[0] = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (scores[i] == scores[i - 1]) {
                rank[i] = rank[i - 1];
            } else {
                rank[i] = rank[i - 1] + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int aliceScore = alice[i];
            if (aliceScore > scores[0]) {
                res[i] = 1;
            } else if (aliceScore < scores[n - 1]) {
                res[i] = rank[n - 1] + 1;
            } else {
                int index = binarySearch(scores, aliceScore);
                res[i] = rank[index];

            }
        }
        return res;

    }

    private static int binarySearch(int[] a, int key) {

        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;

        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if (a[mid] == key) {
                return mid;
            } else if (a[mid] < key && key < a[mid - 1]) {
                return mid;
            } else if (a[mid] > key && key >= a[mid + 1]) {
                return mid + 1;
            } else if (a[mid] < key) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            } else if (a[mid] > key) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

You can refer to this **[link](https://youtu.be/CAyXHTqBIBU)** for a more detailed video explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice) {

      int[] uniqueScores = IntStream.of(scores).distinct().toArray();

        int [] rank = new int [alice.length];

        int startIndex=0;

        for(int j=alice.length-1; j>=0;j--) {


        for(int i=startIndex; i<=uniqueScores.length-1;i++) {

            if (alice[j]<uniqueScores[uniqueScores.length-1]){
                    rank[j]=uniqueScores.length+1;
                    break;
                }

            else if(alice[j]>=uniqueScores[i]) {
                    rank[j]=i+1;
                    startIndex=i;
                    break;
                }

                else{continue;}

            }
    } 
    return rank;
    }
```

Comment: ah sure, next time I will, cuz this is the first time to answer, no idea how to put things here

Comment: Just press edit below of your code and add the things you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in javascript for climbing the Leaderboard Hackerrank problem. The time complexity of the problem can be O(i+j), i is the length of scores and j is the length of alice. The space complexity is O(1).

```
// Complete the climbingLeaderboard function below.
function climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice) {
    const ans = [];
    let count = 0;
    // the alice array is arranged in ascending order
    let j = alice.length - 1;
    for (let i = 0 ; i < scores.length ; i++) {
        const score = scores[i];
        for (; j >= 0 ; j--) {
            if (alice[j] >= score) {
                // if higher than score
                ans.unshift(count+1);
            } else if (i === scores.length - 1) {
                // if smallest
                ans.unshift(count+2);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // actual rank of the score in leaderboard
        if (score !== scores[i-1]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
            List<int> distinct = null;
            List<int> rank = new List<int>();
            foreach (int item in player)
            {
                ranked.Add(item);
                ranked.Sort();
                ranked.Reverse();
                distinct = ranked.Distinct().ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < distinct.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (item == distinct[i])
                    {
                        rank.Add(i + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        return rank;
```

This can be modified by removing the inner for loop also

```
            List<int> distinct = null;
            List<int> rank = new List<int>();
            foreach (int item in player)
            {
                ranked.Add(item);
                ranked.Sort();
                ranked.Reverse();
                distinct = ranked.Distinct().ToList();
                var index = ranked.FindIndex(x => x == item);
                rank.Add(index + 1);
                
            }
        return rank;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is my solution in c# for Hackerrank Climbing the Leaderboard based on C++ answer here.**

```
public static List<int> climbingLeaderboard(List<int> ranked, List<int> player)
{   
    List<int> _ranked = new List<int>();
    
    _ranked.Add(ranked[0]);
    for(int a=1; a < ranked.Count(); a++)
        if(_ranked[_ranked.Count()-1] != ranked[a])
            _ranked.Add(ranked[a]);
          
    int j = _ranked.Count()-1;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < player.Count())
    {
        if(j < 0)
        {
            player[i] = 1;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(player[i] < _ranked[j])
        {
            player[i] = j+2;
            i++;
        }
        else
        if(player[i] == _ranked[j])
        {
            player[i] = j+1;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j--;
        }
    }      
        
    return player;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution in Java for climbing the Leaderboard Hackerrank problem.

```
    // Complete the climbingLeaderboard function below.
static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice) {
  Arrays.sort(scores);
  HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
int[] ar = new int[alice.length];
int sc = 0;


  for(int i=0; i<alice.length; i++){
    sc = 1;
    set.clear();
    for(int j=0; j<scores.length; j++){
       if(alice[i] < scores[j] && !set.contains(scores[j])){
          sc++;
          set.add(scores[j]);
        }
    }
    ar[i] = sc;
  }return ar;

}
```