# Large list size times out practice problem

Tags: c#, list, performance, sorting, dictionary

I was working on a [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem) practice problem and ran into a interesting error 
when finished. This code works on every case except the ones causing it to fail 
(and they are all timeout exceptions)

**Practice Problem** 
The short version of the problem is you are given a leaderboard (int[]) and "alice's" scores (int[]) you have to find what place she got for each score in the leaderboard...View the link above for the whole problem.

**My Solution**

```
    public static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice)
    {
        int[] results = new int[alice.Length]; //The array that stores alice's placements for each score
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> scoresDict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>(); //Key = x place (1st, 2nd, etc), the list is all the numbers that are at x place
        for(int i = 0; i < alice.Length; i++)
        {
            List<int> alicePlace = scores.ToList<int>();

            //Add the score to the array (converted to list for .Add)
            alicePlace.Add(alice[i]);

            //Sorts in reverse order to get the new score in the correct place
            alicePlace = RecalculateScores(alicePlace);

            //Breaks down the scores into the dictionary above
            scoresDict = SeperateScores(alicePlace);

            //Addes the place to the array
            results[i] = GetPlace(scoresDict, alice[i]);
        }

        return results;

    }
    //Returns scores[] in reverse SORTED order
     public static List<int> RecalculateScores(List<int> scores)
    {
        List<int> scoresRet = scores;
        scoresRet.Sort();
        scoresRet.Reverse();
        return scoresRet;
    }
   //Gets the place (key) for where score is in the dict's value list
    public static int GetPlace(Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict, int score)
    {
        foreach (int i in dict.Keys)
        {
             foreach (int ii in dict[i])
            {
                 if (ii == score)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    //Seperates the array into a dictionary by score placement
    public static Dictionary<int, List<int>> SeperateScores(List<int> scores)
    {
        int placeholder = scores[0];
        int currentPlace = 1;
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> scoresByPlace = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Count(); i++)
        {

            if (scores[i] == placeholder)
            {

                if (!scoresByPlace.Keys.Contains(currentPlace) || scoresByPlace[currentPlace] == null)
                {
                    scoresByPlace[currentPlace] = new List<int>();
                }

                scoresByPlace[currentPlace].Add(scores[i]);
                placeholder = scores[i];
            }
            else
            {

                currentPlace++;

                if (!scoresByPlace.Keys.Contains(currentPlace) || scoresByPlace[currentPlace] == null)
                {
                    scoresByPlace[currentPlace] = new List<int>();
                }
                scoresByPlace[currentPlace].Add(scores[i]);

                placeholder = scores[i];
            }


        }
        return scoresByPlace;
    }
```

**Error** 
Whenever it gets tested with a large array amount (2 Million for examples) it returns an timeout exception (probably HackerRank generated to make it harder)

**Attempted solution**
 
Believe it or not but I changed a lot of things on the above code. For one,the results array in the first function used to be a list but I changed to array to make it faster. I feel the dictionary/List is slowing everything down but I need them for the solution (Especially the dictionary). 
 
 Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: If the list is sorted, you can use the [List<T>.BinarySearch Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8) to speed up search. Dictionaries only offer a speed advantage if you look up elements by key, but not if you loop through the keys.

Comment: Lists and arrays will have O(1) access time by index.  The key difference is the ability to resize a list.

Comment: Yeah, I need to be able to resize... Or I could do int[] scores2 = new int[scores1.Length + 1]; Which would give room for the new score. I would still have to copy the original list first then move  the indexes down/up depending on new position so it doesn't seem any faster to me.

Comment: Assuming you really want a hint, one is you don't need to resize - you can compute the rank for each alice score without adding it to the leaderboard. This also means you don't need to re-sort, and you can pre-compute the ranks for existing scores.

Comment: Related: [Hackerrank: Climbing the Leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300009/hackerrank-climbing-the-leaderboard)